# Category checkboxes in upload modal

Tags: categories, media, media-modal

In a project I'm working on, I've enabled categories for attachments using:

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'attachment');
```

In the edit attachment screen in the Media Library you see the normal list of checkboxes, but in the upload modal categories are presented as a comma-separated list of slugs in a textfield, as if they were a non-hierarchical taxonomy. I'm wondering if it's possible to replace this textfield with a list of category chechboxes. I'm trying to do it myself, but there is little documentation about the 3.5 upload modal.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a ticket for that with some code on WordPress Trac: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22938